# comparing watch times of video with watch time coming from app to avoid duplicate entries in db

Tags: php, sql, laravel, lms, intel-video-processing

```
{
    "start":"0",
    "end":"5",
},
{
    "start":"5",
    "end":"25",
},
{
    "start":"20"
    ,"end":"50",
},
{
    "start":"60"
    ,"end":"150",
},
{
    "start":"40"
    ,"end":"60",
},
{
    "start":"0",
    "end":"10",
},
{
    "start":"1",
    "end":"2",
},
{
    "start":"2",
    "end":"3",
},
{
    "start":"40"
    ,"end":"50",
}
```

this is the data stored in the database and i receive payload from the app which sometime have the duplicate entries like the following request

```
[
                [
                    'start' => 0,
                    'end' => 1
                ],
                [
                    'start' => 1,
                    'end' => 2
                ],
                [
                    'start' => 2,
                    'end' => 3
                ],
                [
                    'start' => 4,
                    'end' => 5
                ]
            ]
```

like all these above entries are covered in the interval having start from 0 till 10 so i dont want these to be inserted in database again.

Comment: Multiple videos per user and Multiple track times shouldn't be a problem, that's just relationships in the database. The problem is *overlapping* times! The rest can be dealt with

Comment: yes its also a big issue if i insert them then there will be duplication of data and the entries can be some time numerous.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with some steps you should follow :

1. you take the smallest start from all the "watching" object's arrays and create a new array of array with 1st one's start as this smallest one.
2. then compare the end of that particular start with all other starts as <= and if it satisfies replace the end with that other array's end keep doing it until you solve all the overlaps.
3. calculate the time diff between start and end from all arrays and then sum the differences.
4. calculate the percentage with the sum.

you can save the result from 2. in your database if you need to return it to the frontend as what are the times that a user has watched.

you may not get a clear understanding of this logic by this answer but you can follow this approach to solve your problem.

Comment: can you read the question again as i have changed it a little bit

Comment: I don't get it what you are trying to do either never insert the overlaps or insert all of them why you are doing both the things you are just complicating it. As I can see that you already have 0-10 and 1-2, 2-3. if you don't want to include overlap than just follow the approach I have mentioned.

Comment: thats what an app developer has sent me as a response and i have to insert it without duplicate or overlapping record like if 0 to 5 is in payload then remove 0 to 1 or 2 to 3 because there 2 are already covered by 0 to 5

Comment: merge both array and proceed with the approach i've mentioned in the answer